# Custom post type archive pagination with HTML5Blank theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

Can't get the pagination to work. Here's my archive-work.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main">
        <!-- section -->
        <section>

            <h1><?php _e( 'Work', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>

            <?php get_template_part('loop', 'work'); ?>

            <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

loop-work.php:

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$work = array(
    'post_type' => 'work'
    ,'numberposts' => -1
    ,'posts_per_page' => 2
    ,'paged' => $paged
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $work );

if ($loop->have_posts()): while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,225)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->

        <header>
            <!-- post title -->
            <h2 class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <!-- /post title -->
            <span class="date"><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></span>
        </header>

        <br/><br/>

        <!-- post details -->
        <!--span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span-->
        <!--span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span-->
        <!-- /post details -->

        <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

If I set the default page to 2, it does show the 3rd and 4th entries... so why won't the links show? That's how it's set up in the theme's default archive/loop.

For your reference: https://github.com/toddmotto/html5blank

Thanks.

Comment: Also what's a good way of including a CPT archive/index in the regular menus? or making them available for inclusion? I can manually add the link, but then it isn't recognized as the current menu item/active.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-post-type-archive-links-to-your-menu--wp-25314

Answer (score 0):

Most pagination relies on the `$wp_query` global.
Try changing `$loop` to `$wp_query`

And put this `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `endwhile`.

Comment: Well changing $loop to $wp_query did get the pagination to show up, but when I click, it says not found, and if I go to /?page=2 it still thinks it's page 1